# Pcap magic number on live capture

Tags: c, header-files, pcap, libpcap

Is it possible to catch a correct pcap header on live capture or is it only put in files? All documentation relates to files...

I've managed to extract the magic number with ease from .pcap files using libpcap in Linux with C and Jnetpcap in windows with Java acc. to [1][2].
However, when going through the header struct on live capture (through printf or debug) the field values seem messed up. E.g snaplen value ends up in timezone field and other values make no sense.

I'm using

```
int pcap_loop(pcap_t *p, int cnt, pcap_handler my_callback, u_char *user) 

void my_callback (u_char *args, const struct pcap_file_header *header,   const u_char *packet)
```

Pcap.h:

```
struct pcap_file_header { bpf_u_int32 magic; u_short version_major; u_short version_minor; bpf_int32 thiszone; /* gmt to local correction */ bpf_u_int32 sigfigs; /* accuracy of timestamps */ bpf_u_int32 snaplen; /* max length saved portion of each pkt */ bpf_u_int32 linktype; /* data link type (LINKTYPE_*) */ };
```

[1] http://www.tcpdump.org/pcap/pcap.html
[2] http://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap-savefile.5.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Savefiles have a file header, followed by packet records, each of which has a packet header.  The file header includes a magic number and several other fields.

Live captures do *not* have a file header, and never will have a file header, so they do not have a magic number or any of the other fields from a file header.

If you want to know the snapshot length for a `pcap_t`, call `pcap_snapshot()`.  If you are reading a savefile, it will return the snapshot length that libpcap read from the file header.  If you have a live capture, it will return the snapshot length specified in a `pcap_open_live()` or `pcap_set_snaplen()` call or, if `pcap_create()` and `pcap_activate()` were used without a `pcap_set_snaplen()` call, the default snapshot length that was used.

The timezone value is not returned by libpcap; it is not set in most capture files.

> ```
> void my_callback (u_char *args, const struct pcap_file_header *header,
>                   const u_char *packet)
> ```

The `pcap_loop()` man page says:

```
   typedef void (*pcap_handler)(u_char *user, const struct pcap_pkthdr *h,
                               const u_char *bytes);
```

so the second argument to your callback should be `const struct pcap_pkthdr *`, ***NOT*** `const struct pcap_file_header *`.  `pcap_loop()` will return a packet, *not* a file header; as I said, live captures do not *have* a file header.

Comment: I'm using the pcap_handler the way you and man page suggest for my "real" live capture. The reason I wanted to extract the magic number was due to the fact that it will indicate whether packet header timestamp is in sec and usec OR sec and nsec. So this was a way to capture one packet, determine timestamp resolution and then carry on. I KNOW for a fact that MY system  defines timeval in sec and usec but wanted a way to autocheck this. I can of course dump the first packet to a file and extract the magic number but eeeh. Or I could somehow parse the timeval structure. ..

Comment: Unless you call `pcap_set_tstamp_precision()`, the time stamps your callback will get will ***ALWAYS*** be in seconds and microseconds, even if the system can give you higher-precision time stamps on a live capture or if the file has higher precision.  If you want seconds/nanoseconds time stamps in a live capture, you must try setting the precision with `pcap_set_tstamp_precision()` - if it succeeds, it returns 0, and the time stamps will be in seconds and nanoseconds, otherwise it returns `PCAP_ERROR_TSTAMP_PRECISION_NOTSUP`, and the time stamps will be in seconds and microseconds.